# Brand New Dell Studio 1558 Heatsink fan not working properly

Tags: fan, overheating, heatsink

So here is my situation, I've a Dell Studio 1558 laptop running on Corei3 Processor and about few months ago it stopped working, on powering on there would be no display although I could hear the heatsink fan running.

About few weeks ago I opened the laptop cleaned the heatsink fan and applied fresh thermal paste and after this it started to work again but the problem was the temperature of the processor (core 0, core 1) would remain above 60C even in idle state and recently the heatsink's fan wouldn't start and as a result the laptop wouldn't start due to over-heating.

To fix this I bought a brand new heatsink from eBay and installed it and below is the result:-

1) After installing the new heatsink, I turned on the laptop and visually tried to verify if the fan was working but the fan wasn't working even though this is a brand new heatsink.

2) To troubleshoot the heatsink fan issue, I removed the laptop's battery and cmos battery and pressed the power button for few seconds then installed the batteries and powered it on again and after this the heatsink fan was working.

3) I checked SpeedFan to see the temp and in idle state the temperature was around 45C-50C so the heatsink was working but after few minutes when I opened a browser the display went blank and I had to turn it off via long pressing the power button.

4) Now when I power on the laptop the display is blank and I get this continuous beeps, the heatsink fan is not working either which is obviously causing the processor to over-heat and probably the reason for the continuous beeps.

5) When I was using the old Heatsink and facing over-heating issues I bought a Deepcool cooling pad with 2 fans and it's after I started using this cooling pad that the old heatsink fan stopped working, I'm just mentioning this in case if these 2 additional fans effect the laptop's power consumption and has some effect on the heatsink fan.

I've wasted about a month troubleshooting this laptop, I have assembled and disassembled the laptop at least 20 times by now, so really desperate to get this laptop working again, so any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATED:-
The solution to the heatsink fan problem is repeatedly pressing the F2 button on start up. This is weird but it's working every time. I was trying to get to the bios and that's when I noticed that pressing the F2 for some reason starts the heatsink fan. I've checked it couple of times and it worked every time.

Comment: Laptops are design with very specific and percise heat specifications.  Even the space between the heatsink and the thermal paste is important.  It simply sounds like your hardware cannot be fixed at this point.  If you are getting beeps it means your system isn't even POSTing at this point.  Its likely that issue is connected to the fact you are using two fans instead of the 1 Dell designed the laptop around.

Comment: If this hardware is brand new send it to dell after you extract, copy, and wipe the hdd contained within it.

Comment: The 2 extra fans are external and not inside the laptop, it's a laptop cooling pad with 2 fans and it's powered via usb. I bought the laptop almost 2 years ago so it's out of warranty. Basically I just need to know how to get the heatsink fan to work when the heatsink fan works the pc starts.

Comment: it should just work if it has power.

Comment: Yes I know, I tried running it on battery and also while charging but the fan doesn't work, as soon as I start the pc there is continuous beep and I have to power off.

Comment: Sounds like you should send it to Dell at this point the laptop sounds damaged beyond your ability to fix it

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, I have no intention to give Dell any more of my money :) Next laptop I'll purchase probably from HP or Apple. I've updated the solution to my problem in my question section in case some one else faces this issue.

Comment: If you have a solution post an answer the length of your question makes it rough to see the solution.  A brand new laptop has a warranty for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing a similar situation where the heatsink fan isn't working at startup then try repeatedly pressing F2 as soon as you power on the laptop. I tested this couple of times and it works every time, if I don't press the F2 then the fan doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

it could be that due to the external cooling fans the laptop is not getting hot enough for the internal fan to work, have you tried using the laptop without the external cooling fans to see if the internal fan then works, alternatively, sometimes a BIOS update from the manufacturers website can resolve cooling fan issues.